# How to set computed width on the host element using a directive in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a directive called as `resize` which handles some mouse events and computes `width` on mouse move and it emits the width from the directive.

I am using this directive on a `div` inside a component say `small`. The component `small` has a parent where it is being used. The `small` component has a `width` set to `200px`. Now, I would like to set the width which is being computed in the directive on the host element of the `small` component.

Here is the code:

small.component.html:

```
<div class="root">
 <div>... some elements</div>
 <div class="sizer" resize></div>
</div>
```

small.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnChanges, OnInit, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: "comp-small",
    providers: [SmallService],
    templateUrl: "./small.component.html",
})
export class Small implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
  }
  // some functionality

}
```

small.scss:

```
comp-small {
 width: 200px;
}
```

parent.component.html:

```
<comp-small></comp-small>
<div class="blah"></div>
```

directive resize:

```
import { Directive, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: "[resize]"
})
export class Resize {
    private stPoint: number;
    private endPoint: number;
    private root: HTMLElement;
    private width: number;

    @Output() resizer = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(private _el: ElementRef) {
        this.root = this._el.nativeElement;
        console.log("Root Element", this.root);
    }

    @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
    private _onMouseDown(event) {
       this.stPoint = event.pageX;
       console.log("Starting pt", this.stPoint);
    }

    @HostListener('mousemove', ['$event'])
    private _onMouseMove(event) {
        if (this.stPoint) {
            if (event.type === "mousemove") {
                this._endPoint = event.pageX;
                console.log("end pt: mousemove", this.endPoint);
            } 
            this.width = this.endPoint - this.stPoint;
            console.log("This Width", this.width);
            this.resizer.emit(this.width);
        }
    }

    @HostListener('mouseup', ['$event'])
    private _onMouseUp(event) {
        console.log("Width", this.width);
    }
}
```

How can I set the width of the `comp-small` with the computed width from the directive. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand it correctly. But if you want to emit the width to the component which has this template:

```
<div class="root">
 <div>... some elements</div>
 <div class="sizer" resize></div>
</div>
```

Then do it like this:

```
<div class="root">
 <div>... some elements</div>
 <div class="sizer" resize (resizer)="onResize($event)"></div>
</div>
```

And in small.component.ts something like this:

```
constructor(
  private renderer: Renderer2,
  private elementRef: ElementRef,
) {}

onResize(width) {
  this.renderer.setStyle(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'width', `${width}px`);
}
```

Comment: In this case, the `elementRef.nativeElement` would give you the `div` with class `root`. I don't want to set `width` on it. I want to set the `width` on the component selector itself which is `comp-small` which is being used in the parent component.

Comment: if the <div class="root"> is in the comp-small template then it should be the component, not the div.root. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I did try it. It doesn't work. I want to set the width on the host element itself. The `<div class="root">` is the child element of the `comp-small`. When you do `this.elementRef.nativeElement`, that would give a reference to the `div` with class `root` whereas I want to access the parent of it.